# InDesign: current page number adjustment

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, master-page

Can't figure out if there's a way to add a '0' (zero) before the current page number on a master page, so that only pages 1 to 9 get listed as '01', '02', etc instead of '1', '2', etc. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After defined the Marker > Current Page Number at the Master,

- Click the first page
- **Menu Layout** > **Number & Section Options...** > **Page Numbering** > Select the Style

[image: numbering]

**Result**

[image: Pages]

Comment: Oh ok this was right in front of me :) thanks